# SwiftUI: Fill title bar area and size window to content on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I want to create a content-sized, non-resizable window with an image taking full height including the title bar area. I hid the title bar and used `ignoresSafeArea()` on the outermost view. For some reason, SwiftUI calculates the window height as if the title bar is still present:

[image]

If I omit `ignoresSafeArea()` then the content stays below the title bar area. Curiously, background color of inner views propagates all the way to the top edge of the window:

[image]

In both of the above cases the window is not resizable, as requested by `windowResizability(.contentSize)`.

If I add infinite `maxHeight` to one of the inner views then the view becomes vertically resizable, but can't resize smaller than fixed frame's height + title bar height. When both elements (or the `HStack`) have infinite `maxHeight` applied, the window is resizable vertically but does not adjust to the content size initially; it still shows the bottom margin the size of the title bar:

[image]

The behavior is the same on Ventura and Sonoma beta with XCode 15 Beta 4.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this a bug with SwiftUI? Curious if there is a solution to this by using some AppKit incantations or some other way?

This is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FullViewApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
        .windowResizability(.contentSize)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var infiniteH = true
    @State private var ignoreSafe = true
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            Image("city")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .border(.green, width: 2)
                .frame(width: 256, height: 256, alignment: .top)
                .modifier(HFrame(apply: infiniteH))
                .border(.red)
                .background(.indigo)
                
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Toggle("Infinite height", isOn: $infiniteH)
                    .toggleStyle(.switch)
                Toggle("Ignore safe area", isOn: $ignoreSafe)
                    .toggleStyle(.switch)
            }
            .padding(5)
            .frame(width: 256, height: 256, alignment: .top)
            .border(.green, width: 2)
            .modifier(HFrame(apply: infiniteH))
            .border(.red)
            .background(.orange)
        }
        .modifier(IgnoreSafeArea(apply: ignoreSafe))
    }
}

struct HFrame : ViewModifier {
    var apply : Bool
    
    @ViewBuilder func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if apply {
            content.frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}

struct IgnoreSafeArea : ViewModifier {
    var apply: Bool
    
    @ViewBuilder func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if apply {
            content.ignoresSafeArea()
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```